# What is more efficient, pairing based cryptography or non pairing based cryptography?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, pairings

As far as I know non pairing pairing based cryptography is less time consuming than pairing based because, pairing based uses complex operations. Are there any advantages of pairing based cryptography over elliptic curves without using pairing based cryptography?

Comment: I think if you add more context to the question to make it more specific, we can reopen this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can express your operation well using plain groups, go with normal elliptic curves. But the pairing adds additional mathematical structure, which enables new algorithms.

Some examples:

- [BLS signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh-Lynn-Shacham)

  They're verifiably deterministic and small, 2x security level, instead of 3 to 4 times, with DSA/Schnorr/ElGamal signatures.

  These  use the pairing as a decisional Diffie-Hellman oracle.
- Identity based encryption using the [Boneh–Franklin scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh-Franklin_scheme).

Comment: pairing based have any advantage over without using pairing based

Comment: @Nubila I just posted two schemes that require pairings, what more do you want?

Comment: I am doing my mtech projct. It is the security of data sharing in cloud. For this I would like to use cerificateless cryptography.the base paper is implemented as without using pairing . so I want to modify it to with pairing scheme. So i want to know that which have any advantage..

Comment: Will u please help me??

Comment: @Nubila You didn't even link the paper you're talking about. You didn't give enough context. Your question isn't answerable like that.

Comment: My paper is "An Efficient Certificateless Encryption for
Secure Data Sharing in Public Clouds"

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: It's pretty obvious: Pairings are useful, if you need pairings. If you don't then, they aren't. Moreover, in pairing friendly groups the "normal" DH problem is easy to solve, so just transferring schemes from one group into the other might pose problems.